# Retrive Opportunity Using CRM Organization Webservice C# in Windows rt(Windows 8) Application

Tags: windows-8, dynamics-crm-2011

I want to create a windows 8 metro application for retrieving and showing all the opportunity entity of organization. Any idea ? how to do so?

I have achieved the same for desktop application and it working fine now I want to create the same application for the Windows 8.

Comment: Is your question how to create a windows 8 app, or how to call CRM from a windows 8 app?

Comment: how to call CRM from a windows 8 app?

Comment: This question would be a lot less vague if you could tell us what you've already tried, and what problems you've encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes should get reference to the organization service of the CRM server which will help you to

insert an retrieve all kind of entities  as the link describes

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328416.aspx